# Statically compiling custom elements

Tags: html

I love custom elements to organize the content of a webpage in a simple way, thinking about the semantics without caring about the gory details.

It looks like, though, that in order to use custom elements, I either need to rely on JavaScript or on modern browsers.

Is there any *compiler* out there that allows me to statically translate some custom elements to a standard set of elements?

I'm also very curious about why such approach seems to be very unpopular (couldn't find any tool to do the job), compared to using JavaScript...

Comment: First thing I can think of: XSLT

Answer (score 0):

Well... ASP.NET WebForms does that. It uses custom elements ("controls") that produce the actual HTML in  a given context. You could build a simple tool that builds the static HTML out of that.

Of course, it's probably incredibly overblown for your scenario, but it works :D

Even in server-side code, this is somewhat unusual - most servers and languages usually use another kind of markup to combine presentation and code in one. Even "modern" ASP.NET applications tend to ignore controls. But they sure are useful :)